# Databricks or Functions with ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm using ADF to output some reports to pdf (at least that's the goal.)

I'm using ADF to output a csv to a storage blob and I would like to ingest that, do some formatting and stats work (with scipy and matplotlib in python) and export as a pdf to the same container. This would be run once a month, and I may do a few other things like this, but they are periodical reports at the most, no streaming or anything like that.

From an architectural stand point, would this be a good application for an Azure Function (which I have some experience), or Azure Databricks (which I will want some experience in).

My first thought is the Azure Functions, since they are serverless and pay-as-you-go. But I don't know too much about Databricks except that it's primarily used for big data and long running jobs.

Comment: Strongly agree with answer, use an Azure function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databricks would be almost certainly an overkill for this. So yes, Azure Function for Python sounds like a perfect fit for your scenario.